# Should Skeptics.SE be moved to the 'Science' section?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As of 25 May 2015, skeptics.se is not considered in the science section of Stack Exchange:

[image]

Don't you think it ought to be?

(This topic has been already [brought to meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257371/move-skeptics-stack-exchange-to-the-science-section/257403?noredirect=1#comment839517_257403))

Comment: I agree, and I also pointed this out to SE. The decision is justified by the fact that scientific skepticism is undeniably part of culture (along with science), but it's not a science. On the other hand, feel free to debate this,  And if any strong consensus arises, any of the mods can bring it to the attention of SE.

Answer (score 12):

Skeptics.SE simply applies principles of good [journalistic accuracy](http://ethics.npr.org/category/a1-accuracy/) to a wide range of topics. We follow the evidence, and attempt to present the best of it contextualized within the entire body of research, but answers cannot do original research. So, we are not *doing* scientific scepticism. Also, scientific topics have no special status above other topics on this site.

Comment: completely agree, there seems to be a common public conflation between "scientific" and "rational" (or even just "good").  There is nothing wrong with good journalism, and it only causes problems with moderation to continually describe the site as implementing "scientific skepticism" when that is not what it *actually* does.  Moving it to the science category would only reinforce that misunderstanding.

Comment: "Scientific literature comprises scientific publications that report original empirical and theoretical work in the natural and social sciences", in that case "scientific literature" is definitely not what SkepticsSE aims for as **original** empirical and theoretical work is not accepted.  We don't report original empirical or theoretical work, we have to limit ourselves to summarizing and contextualizing the work of others.  BTW do you have a source for "certified knowledge" other than Merton, it doesn't seem to crop up in any of my philosophy of science texts.  I suspect it is rather dated.

Comment: Regarding "journalism", it doesn't strictly apply to news, there is for instance science journalism http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_journalism .  SkepticsSE is basically adopting the principles of science journalism to a variety of topics, not all of which are science.  The distinction is not always very clear, for instance National Geographic Magazine is clearly journalism, it isn't about news, and not all of it is science journalism.

Comment: Much better Nomen Agentis, good edit.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree: Skeptics is not about science. It covers a lot of topics. Sure, many of these topics are science, but there are also many that aren't. Out of the [top 36 tags](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tags), at a glance, only half are related to science.

More importantly, **Skeptics.SE rejects a pure scientific approach**. A pure scientific approach is explicitly off-topic on Skeptics.SE: “I did the experiment and it shows that …” or “Here's the proof: …” are not appropriate answers here. In order to be appropriate, these answers would have to contain “… and I published my results in this peer-reviewed paper”. The clincher that makes an answer acceptable on Skeptics.SE is citations, i.e. arguments from authority. Arguments from authority are irrelevant to science in itself, they are only relevant (and of course very important) to the process of discovering science. If a peer-reviewed paper states something that is contradicted by an experiment or by logic, that makes this paper bad science. The world doesn't care that the paper has been accepted.

Sure, it is often expected that the authorities cited here would apply a scientific method, but the science is not happening *here*.

Given that Skeptics.SE works on a social basis — it's about finding citations — the proper category would be one that encompasses social topics, together with other applied sociology sites: Politics, Academia, Workplace, Community Building, etc.

Comment: Yes, there seems a misconception that scientists reference previous work as proof that an assertion is true, however this is incorrect.  Most scientists know that peer-review is no guarantee that a journal paper is correct (you only need to have your own work reviewed and review the work of others to know why that is the case) and reference other work (a) to acknowledge priority and (b) so that the reader knows where to find out about the basis for the assertion.

Comment: "OK. We are a site which reports scientific findings" which is what good journalists do when reporting on science stories.  However, that is journalism, not "scientific skepticism".  If we genuinely adopted scientific skepticism here, then pure logic or individual research would be perfectly acceptable.  Scientists do not automatically trust peer-reviewed journal papers, as I said you only need to be involved in peer review (from both sides) to see why it can never be more than a basic sanity check.

Comment: @Gilles thanks for rephrasing the answer. I've removed my comments as obsolete.

Comment: I done a pretty severe purge of the comments because Sklivvz comments which triggered the discussion had been removed, because they had diverged from the actual answer into arguing about definitions and because the tone was of mutual exasperation rather than assuming good will. I encourage you to discuss it in chat (nicely!) or post an alternative answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is 'History' a science?

Skeptics include 400 [history](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) topics, nearly 200 [politics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politics) topics, more than 100 [law](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) questions, 400 not-exactly-scientific topics about the [united-states](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states), nearly 200 [economics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics) questions (economics is defined as a "social science"); plus 100s of other topics about [crime](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crime), [movies](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies), [news](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/news), [sport](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sport), [military](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military), [government](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government), etc.

Comment: @georgechalhoub I think I disagree with the data in your post. If you say "this is a bag of apples", and when I look in the bag I see that a large percentage of its contents is potatoes ...

Comment: I said it is a bag of apples and potatoes. Don't forget [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257392/263251) we overlap with almost all science categories, but when it comes to culture it is just two categories.

Comment: @georgechalhoub I think I've finally understood your argument. I suppose mine is that if it includes potatoes then it doesn't belong on the apples shelf. If it contains both then it belongs on the "produce" shelf. I think that specific sciences are narrow subjects whereas culture is a broad subject. Culture includes science; science doesn't include culture. Culture means, basically, "society's state-of-the-art": e.g. defined as "the arts and other manifestations of human intellectual achievement regarded collectively" ... so 21st century culture includes science (and history, etc.).

Comment: Perhaps you dislike [the neighborhood](http://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation): languages, religions, hobbies, and ... bicycles. :-)

Answer (score 0):

FYI [the data in this answer](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3242/2703) might be  misleading (cherry-picked). In fact our most popular tags are:

- [medical-science](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical-science) × 843
- [nutrition](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) **× 485**
- [history](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) **× 424**
- [united-states](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) **× 420**
- [biology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology) × 308
- [psychology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology) × 279
- [physiology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physiology) × 239
- [physics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) × 205
- [economics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics) × 189
- [politics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politics) **× 183**
- [zoology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoology) **× 172**
- [environmental-health](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environmental-health) **× 156**
- [alternative-medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-medicine) **× 148**
- [religion](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion) **× 128**
- [law](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) **× 122**
- [cars](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) **× 121**
- [natural-remedies](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-remedies) **× 115**
- [safety](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) **× 106**
- [chemistry](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) × 105
- **44 other tags between chemistry and astronomy**
- [astronomy](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronomy) × 47

Comment: I am not sure what bold means exactly but "nutrition", "zoology", "alternative-medicine" are all scientific topics. Alternative medicine methods such as homeopathy, or nutrition are studied by medical researchers just like mainstream medicine. Zoology is a science.

Comment: It just means they were missing from [the list originally presented](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/3242/2703).

Answer (score -1):

Although we don't really strictly fit anywhere, I think we fit better under "Science", Our most popular tags are:

- [medical-science](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical-science) × 843
- [biology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology) × 308
- [psychology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology) × 279
- [physiology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physiology) × 239
- [physics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) × 205
- [economics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics) × 189
- [chemistry](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) × 105
- [astronomy](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronomy) × 47

Quoting [moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257392/263251) Sklivvz:

> Our site fit many categories at an abstract level.
>
> Science, because it overlaps with:
>
> Physics 
> Biology
> Chemistry
> Economics
> Philosophy
> Earth Science
> Astronomy
> Life and arts, because it overlaps with:
>
> Health
> Life Hacks
> Personal Productivity
> Culture, because it overlaps with:
>
> Politics
> History
>
> Of all the categories where it could fit, Culture is unfortunately the least overlapping and science is the most overlapping.

On this website, we strictly [practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_skepticism):

> questioning whether claims are supported by empirical research and have reproducibility, as part of a methodological norm pursuing "the extension of certified knowledge"

Though, we're not really a science website, I'm suggesting moving our site to the science section since we overlap with most of the topics there.

Comment: The list of tags in this answer might be misleading: see also [this answer](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/3243/2703).

Comment: This answer got flagged. Can you please explain why you have two conflicting answers?

Comment: @Oddthinking It was because further to now-deleted comments under [this answer of mine](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/3229/2703), I cut this answer from george's question and posted it here (so this is actually originally george's answer, perhaps intended to disagree with or ignore the premise of my first answer). Then I reviewed the data in this answer and disagreed with it: I didn't want to edit this answer because I see it as being George's and my editing it would contradict the author's intent (i.e. be a "hostile edit") and so I posted revised data as a different (third) answer.